# Reducing rows and expanding columns of data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data.frame in R.

```
> a <- data.frame(year = c(2001,2001,2001,2001), country = c("Japan", "Japan","US","US"), type = c("a","b","a","b"), amount = c(35,67,39,45))
> a
  year country type amount
1 2001   Japan    a     35
2 2001   Japan    b     67
3 2001      US    a     39
4 2001      US    b     45
```

How should I transform this into a data.frame that looks like this?

```
  year country type.a type.b
1 2001   Japan     35     67
2 2001      US     39     45
```

Basically I want the number of rows to be the number of (year x country) pairs, and I want to create additional columns for each type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base solution, but requires renaming columns and rows

```
reshape(a, v.names="amount", timevar="type", idvar="country", direction="wide")
  year country amount.a amount.b
1 2001   Japan       35       67
3 2001      US       39       45
```

reshape2 solution

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(a, year+country ~ paste("type", type, sep="."), value.var="amount")

  year country type.a type.b
1 2001   Japan     35     67
2 2001      US     39     45
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use `spread` in the `tidyr` package and `rename` in the `dplyr` package to deliver the expected outcome.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

spread(a,type, amount) %>%
rename(type.a = a, type.b = b)

#  year country type.a type.b
#1 2001   Japan     35     67
#2 2001      US     39     45
```